# Z-Index Issue - image not clickable

Tags: css

I am having an z-index issue with a logo. It is covered by some other divs and only part of it is clickable. I have set the z-index to max and for the other divs covering it to lower values but unfortunately to no avail. The website in question is the following: https://poche.ro/pick-a-box/

Also the logo in question is in the upper left corner.
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: change the `z-index` of `.navigation-anchor` to `998`.

Comment: Don't use 2 `div`'s with the same `id="topbar"`

Comment: With correct use of floating, you can position your logo left of the menu, without them overlapping like this. You can learn more about floating [over here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

Comment: thanks for your time guys! I have done what Jyoti suggested and it works. However, it renders the menu on the right unusable (unclickable).

Comment: JiFus! Thanks for the suggestion. I am not very experienced with css but I do know that it would be an optimal solution. Got lost in code and ended up ruining something else. Would love to master the "float"! :) When I tried to adjust it with float, it still comes up as a z index issue. only clickable on the top of the logo. :(

Comment: Alex, you need to change the html structure and css to fix the issue, otherwise its difficult to get the exact output.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Karthik! Any suggestions on what I could do to fix it?